# how to make sql query with and in yii active record?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am new in Yii. Now i have encountered problem with active record in yii.

So , I have normal sql here :

```
 $sqlText = "SELECT *
        FROM tbl_webservicetokens
        WHERE clienttoken = '{$appToken}'
            AND
              systimestamp < expiredate";
```

I want to use active record. But i endeavored

```
$post=TBLWEBSERVICETOKENS::model()->find(
        'CLIENTTOKEN=:appToken AND EXPIREDATE>:systimestamp', 
        array(
            ':appToken'=>$appToken,
            ':systimestamp'=>'systimestamp'));
```

But i had error!
any idea?

Comment: $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "ID = 1212 AND CLIENTTOKEN = 'ws546b041c85ad38a2c1f4224e1e39fe09cf76a3c8703c5'";
$models = TBLWEBSERVICETOKENS::model()->findAll($criteria);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($models);
echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. I think this will work for you.

```
 $post= TBLWEBSERVICETOKENS::model()->find(array(
       'select'=>'*',
       'condition'=>'CLIENTTOKEN=:appToken AND EXPIREDATE>:systimestamp',
       'params'=>array(':appToken'=>$appToken,':systimestamp'=>'systimestamp'))
       );
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, i have error   `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: ORA-01858:

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong data type (string) for the date time field have you noted that

```
$post=TBLWEBSERVICETOKENS::model()->find(
        'CLIENTTOKEN=:appToken AND EXPIREDATE>:systimestamp', 
        array(
            ':appToken'=>$appToken,
            ':systimestamp'=>$systimestamp)); //$systimestamp where your time data type value resides
```

If you still have the error
[Read Me!!!](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01858.php)

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems to me i find answer:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
```

$criteria->condition = "ID = 1212 AND CLIENTTOKEN = 'ws546b041c85ad38a2c1f4224e1e39fe09cf76a3c8703c5'";
$models = TBLWEBSERVICETOKENS::model()->findAll($criteria);